Copying HTML table to clipboard to MS Excel
I write a program in Java that create an HTML Table when the user press a button on my Web application. At the end of the creation, the table is copied in the clipboard, and the user paste the clipboard in MS Excel program. The table must have some graphic setting, one of them is that the cells have a minimum fixed width. The table must bee saved in XSLX format after copied in MS Office
Example of HTML table:
    <table>
      <tr>
            <th>Label 1</th>
            <th>Label 2</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Short</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
    <td>Long long long long long long long long long</td>
      </tr>
</table>

I was able to do all that I want, except for make a fixed default minimum length of the cells. I tried to do the attempts below:
<td width="300px">1</td>

<td width="300">1</td>

<table>
     <col width="300" />
    <td>1</td>
</table>

<table>
        <colgroup>
        <col width="300">
    </colgroup>
    <td>1</td>
</table>

But nothing works. Could you help me?

Sorry I am kind of rusty with this... Have you tried something like <table><tr><th width="300">Label 1</th><th width="300">Label 2</th></tr><tr><td width="300">1</td><td width="300">Short</td></tr><tr><td width="300">2</td><td width="300">Long long long long long long long long long</td></tr></table>

In html, I think it should be <td style="width: 300px">xxx</td>. Not sure about copy/paste into excel

I assume you're not copying the actual HTML, but you're copying the rendered table and pasting that into Excel?  Is your expectation that by adjusting the HTML styles for width, it'll force Excel to react accordingly?  To do that, you'd have to use VBA to parse the clipboard and generate your Excel table accordingly.

Thank you  Siddharth Rout and lance-java but I had already tried the attempts that you had suggested, but the columns still not change the width.

SaintFrag, the HTML table is rendered on the browser. I still have the data used to fill the table, I use this data to regenerate the HTML table in order to remove element not needed in MS Excel, like the part of source code for sorting, then I get the HTML string and copy it directly on clipboard. The user then paste the clipboard in MS Excel.

I don't believe you can affect Excel column widths through a direct paste of HTML code, unless perhaps an older version like Excel 2010 could do so.  There are multiple resources from around that era that seem to indicate success on this matter, but I can't get them to work myself.
